# din-a6 four times on din-a4

Tags: inkscape

I want to print 4 din-a6 postcards on a din-a4 paper. How would you do this with inkscape?

The postcard should be duplex. I could calculate it myself, but I guess there is a tool, since this is a common task

Thank you.

Comment: Do you simply need to have a layout of four of the front of the postcard as one file and four of the back as another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inkscape does not have an imposition engine, which is what it sounds like you're trying to do.

I would recommend exporting your file to a PDF and using a tool like [JPdfTweak](http://jpdftweak.sourceforge.net/) for handling your imposition needs. It takes a bit of experimentation to understand what it does and how it does it, but once you get the hang of how to use it, JPdfTweak can be very useful.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link to jpdftweak. It does what I searched for. I create the DIN-A4 PDF page and jpdftweak has a preset for 4on1. You just need to tell jpdftweak that you want the first page four times. Per default it puts pages 1,2,3,4 on it.